# XSLT problem: Search in strings for substring "&quot;" or "&amp;#x003E;"

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm learning XSLT and at the moment I'm really stuck and can't find a solution. I really would appreciate if you could help me with this.
Beneath you can find an example

value of $string:

```
&amp;#x003C;img src=&quot;Afbeeldingen_Hotpot/beer.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;afbeelding van een beer&quot; title=&quot;beer&quot; width=&quot;170&quot; height=&quot;144&quot; style=&quot;display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;&quot; style=&quot;float:center;&quot; /&amp;#x003E;
```

My goal is to filter out the height of the image... In this example "144".
the functx:index-of-string I got from this website: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_index-of-string.html

This the XSLT code I now use:

```
    <xsl:variable name="positionHeight" as="xs:integer"><xsl:value-of select="functx:index-of-string($string,'height=') + 8"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="partStringHeight" as="xs:string"><xsl:value-of select="substring($string,$positionHeight)"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lengthHeight" as="xs:integer"><xsl:value-of select="functx:index-of-string($partStringHeight,'style=' - 3)"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="height" as="xs:string"><xsl:sequence select="substring($partStringHeight,1,$lengthHeight)"/></xsl:variable>
```

Beneath the XSLT code I want to use, but gives an error because the index-of-string for """ is zero".

```
    <xsl:variable name="positionHeight" as="xs:integer"><xsl:value-of select="functx:index-of-string($string,'height=') + 8"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="partStringHeight" as="xs:string"><xsl:value-of select="substring($string,$positionHeight)"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lengthHeight" as="xs:integer"><xsl:value-of select="functx:index-of-string($partStringHeight,'&quot;' - 1)"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="height" as="xs:string"><xsl:sequence select="substring($partStringHeight,1,$lengthHeight)"/></xsl:variable>
```

Is there a way to get the index of a substrings like:

```
&quot; and &amp;#x003E;
```

Because I have many strings were I need the height but where "style=" does not occur..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution in XSLT is to put the inconvenient string into the value of a variable (not using `select`):

```
<xsl:variable name="quot">"</xsl:variable>
```

Then

```
<xsl:variable name="lengthHeight" as="xs:integer"
   select="functx:index-of-string($partStringHeight,$quot) - 1" />
```

Also, notice that you've put the `- 3` or `- 1` **inside** the `index-of-string()` parentheses. Surely you want to subtract 3 or 1 from the **return value** of `index-of-string()`? Because it doesn't really make sense to subtract 3 or 1 from `"`.

Also, using `<xsl:value-of />` inside a variable definition body like that is usually redundant. I removed it.

Finally, you can use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` to get what you want with less hassle:

```
<xsl:variable name="beforeHeight" as="xs:integer">height="</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="afterHeight" as="xs:string">" style=</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="height" as="xs:string"
  select="substring-before(substring-after($string, $beforeHeight), $afterHeight)" />
```

Actually I'm not sure from your question whether the input string value you showed at the top was before or after XML parsing. If it was after parsing, i.e. the string data itself contains `&quot;` rather than `"`, then put in `&quot;` but you need to escape the `&` as `&amp;`:

```
<xsl:variable name="beforeHeight" as="xs:integer">height=&amp;quot;</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="afterHeight" as="xs:string">&amp;quot; style=</xsl:variable>
```

In this case you would not have quotation marks in your strings, so you wouldn't need to put the values in variables like that; but it's probably a good idea for readability.

Similarly `&amp;#x003e` would need to be escaped as `&amp;amp;#x003e`.

Comment: Wauw thanks for the clear explanation! The string is before the transformation... To bad I have to go now, but I'll check it out tomorrow!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's working now and use substring-before and after which is a lot better! :)